# Symfony2 many to one relation from different entities: parent of extended class also persisted

Tags: symfony, many-to-one

I have a 3 different classes (A, B, C) who are related to a class D (with some fields). As class D never gets updated but I create an updated version of it every time it's saved, I want D to refer to A, but not the other way around.

So far so good.

The thing is that I want to have that many to one relationship from D to A but another record of D could refer to B or C.

I thought about creating a base class D, with all the common fields I need, and then create classes Da, Db and Dc extending D, and the only additional field of Da, Db and Dc would be the many to one relation to either A, B or C respectively.

I assume this would create 3 tables: Da, Db and Dc, each with the corresponding foreign keys to A, B, C. Right?

Any other way to solve this issue?

EDIT: My D class is the following:

```
<?php
// src/AppBundle/Entity/Tolerance.php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/** @@ORM\MappedSuperclass */
class Tolerance
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    protected $risk;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    protected $scope;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    protected $budget;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    protected $schedule;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    protected $benefit;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     */
    protected $timestamp;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User")
     */    
    protected $changedBy;    


    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->timestamp = new \DateTime();
    }

// getters and setters follow
}
```

And my Da class is:

```
<?php
// src/AppBundle/Entity/StageTolerance.php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use AppBundle\Entity\Tolerance as BaseTolerance;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Entity\StageToleranceRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="stage_tolerances")
 */
class StageTolerance extends BaseTolerance
{

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Stage")
     */    
    protected $stage;

    // getters and setters follow
}
```

Is this the right way to solve the issue?

Thanks!

Comment: Can the classes A B and C to be combined into a single entity with type choice? Or need to use them as an object with different relationships to other entities? I think, If you can't combined it, you are doing right.

Comment: They can be a single class with type choice, but then I need a reference to the right "father". I could of course have 3 many to many relationship, 2 of them null and the other pointing to the right father (identified by the "type" field) but I don't know if it's worthy or more maintainable...

Comment: Dont create 3 relationships, just create one. Tolerance< - OneToMany -> EntityTolerance(with type)->ManyToMany->(self in $father). When you create father, you need just check correct type, or set in manualy.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand it. If you have time I'd really appreciate a more elaborated answer, otherwise no problem, I'll stick with my solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is good. However, you can select the type of inheritance. There is the usual type (yours), single table and class table inheritance. Choose one of these types which suits your needs. Read the [doc](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html) for more info.